# Android Intent causes a blue layer over the screen

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Using GoogleSingIn I exectute an Intent to get the response for the login. But when I use it, a blue layer appears over the game.

my code when I use the Intent (blue layer appears over the screen):

```
GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

[image: this is the result of my game]
Now, my code when I avoid the Intent line code (and this it what I am expecting):

```
GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
//Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
//startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
loadUrl(launchApp);
```

[image: this is the result of my game]
So, How can I delete this blue layer?

[EDITED]
I tried to use a listener to avoid the Intent, and the blue layer still there:

```
GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {...});
```

so I still facing the error :(

Comment: have you tried this with different devices or different SDKs?

Comment: Hi @mtotoWamkwe I tried with, API 26 (Oreo), API 27 (Oreo), API 28 (Pie) ... and the blue layer appears with all of them.